# How can you translate a map latitude and longitude to a pixel coordinate using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms.maps

I have to translate a latitude and longitude shown on the map to a screen coordinate.

I've searched around the web for solutions and it seems like there used to be something called Projection which had a solution for this but it's no longer accessible through Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.

It would be optimal if there was some sort of method to translate coordinates between lat and long to screen- x and y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a test in the mapRender of `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` in Android.project and found you can use `Projection` in the renderer.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {

                var projection = NativeMap.Projection;

                projection.ToScreenLocation();
                projection.FromScreenLocation();
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
                Control.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
```

Then you can call  `projection.ToScreenLocation();` and `projection.FromScreenLocation();` to translate the points. I think it's almost same if you use a `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps`.

Refer: [Projection](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)) and [custom-renderer/map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin)